# $Error variable is $Null but $_ contains error in Catch

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I have PS module that contains a number of scripts for individual functions.  There is also a "library" script with a number of helper functions that get called by the functions used in the module.

Let's call the outer function `ReadWeb`, and it uses a helper function `ParseXML`.

I encountered an issue this week with error handling in the inner helper `ParseXML` function.  That function contains a try/catch, and in the catch I interrogate:

`$Error[0].Exception.InnerException.Message`

...in order to pass the error back to the outer scope as a variable and determine if `ParseXML` worked.

For a particular case, I was getting an indexing error when I called `ReadWeb`.  The root cause turned out to be the `$Error` object in the `Catch` block in `ParseXML` was coming back `$Null`.

I changed the error handling to check for a `$Error -eq $Null` and if it is, use `$_` in the `Catch` to determine what the error message is.

My question is: **what would cause `$Error` to be `$null` inside the `Catch`?**

Comment: Did you try to isolate the problem into a reduced test case which you can publish here?

Comment: @Neolisk I haven't because of the trouble involved in the various scopes.  I have a module with a script file that calls another function in another module that calls a function in the library.

Comment: Well, it could help to know more about your problem - code, classes, anything. Right now it sounds weird, but that's about it.

Comment: I can try to add some more detail a little later today if necessary.  It's non-trivial to create a reduced case for this.

Comment: I understand. However, it's also non-trivial to give an answer without knowing any specifics. :)

Comment: Are you positive that $error was null or was `$Error[0].Exception.InnerException.Message` null? $error is an read-only array of error records, so unless you've never had an error in your PS session it will always contain something. However individual errors may populate different fields in which case InnerException may not be present.

Comment: @user2460798 I'm sure that `$Error` was null.  I do a check for that at the top of the `catch` to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: answer based on Powershell 3.

`$error` is an automatic variable handled by Powershell: 3rd § of the LONG DESCRIPTION in [about_Try_Catch_Finally](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847793%28v=wps.620%29.aspx).

It is considered as the context of the Catch block, thus being available as `$_`.
Since Catch block is a different block than Try, the `$error` automatic variable is reset and valued `$null`.

Comment: Recommending use of `$_` to access the error at hand instead of `$Error[0]` is the right thing to do.
The link is dead now, but perhaps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/lang-spec/chapter-08?view=powershell-7.2#87-the-tryfinally-statement
is a suitable replacement. However, I don't think your explanation re `$Error` is correct (at least not in 5.1+), given that _outside modules_, `$Error[0]` _is_ the 
same as `$_`. _Inside modules_, it seems that an unused module-level copy of `$Error` hides the global one (possibly a bug), which `$global:Error` can work around.

Comment: @mkelement0: question was legit 8 years ago, with powershell 2 to 4 available, so was my answer :)

Comment: The question is still legit, but your answer never was, from what I can tell (as argued in my previous comment).

Answer (score 2):

Note: The following applies to Windows PowerShell as well as to [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) versions up to a least v7.3.7 (current as of this writing).

- Accessing **the error at hand inside a `catch` block** should indeed be done via the **[automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_)**.
- ***Inside a module*, `$Error`** isn't `$null`, but surprisingly is **an *always-empty* collection** (of type [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList)); therefore, **`$Error[0]`** - which in `catch` blocks *outside* modules is the same as `$_` - is **unexpectedly `$null` in modules**:

  - What technically happens is that **modules have an unused, *module-local copy* of `$Error`**, which ***shadows* (hides) the true `$Error` variable** that is located in the *global* scope.

    - When an error is automatically *recorded* from inside a module, however, it *is* added to the *global* `$Error` collection - just like in code running *outside* of modules.
    - As it turns out, the unused, useless module-level copy of `$Error` is an accidental remnant of functionality that was never implemented: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11457624/45375) for the history, and [GitHub issue #20458](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20458) for a discussion about fixing the problem.
  - Therefore, a **workaround** is to use `$global:Error` instead (which is only necessary if you need access to *previous* errors; as stated, for the *current* one, use `$_`).

The following sample code illustrates the problem:

```bash
$Error.Clear()

# Define a dynamic module that exports sample function 'foo'.
$null = New-Module {

  Function foo {
    try {
      1 / 0     # Provoke an error that can be caught.
    }
    catch {
      $varNames =   '$Error', '$global:Error', '$_'
      $varValues =   $Error,   $global:Error,   $_
      foreach ($i in 0..($varNames.Count-1)) {
        [pscustomobject] @{
          Name = $varNames[$i]
          Type = $varValues[$i].GetType().FullName
          Value = $varValues[$i]
        }
      }
    }
  }

}

foo
```

Output; note how the value of `$Error` is `{}`, indicating an *empty collection*:

```bash
Name          Type                                     Value
----          ----                                     -----
$Error        System.Collections.ArrayList             {}
$global:Error System.Collections.ArrayList             {Attempted to divide by zero.}
$_            System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord Attempted to divide by zero.
```

Answer (score 0):

$error and try / catch are different beasts in PowerShell.

try / catch catches terminating errors, but won't catch a Write-Error (cause it's non terminating).

$error is a list of all errors encountered (including ones swallowed up when -ErrorAction silentlycontinue is used).

$_ is the current error in a try/catch block.

I'd guess that your underlying function calls Write-Error, and you want that to go cleanly into a try/catch.  To make this be a terminating error as well, use -ErrorAction Stop.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing sets ErrorAction at all, and I did try to set `$ErrorActionPreference` to check this behavior as well.  I'm not sure how `$Error` can be `$null` inside the catch block, though.  If we are inside a catch block, a terminating error has occurred regardless.