# PowerShell error variable loses the content

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I have a quite big project with many functions in there.
Just 2 questions:

1. What would be here the "best practice" regarding Error-Handling? To use a local handling per Function, or use only one Error-Logging in the Main-Section?
2. The tricky part (!), let's have a look at the strange Error behaviour in the function F_XXX: only $_ delivers an error message, $Error[0] is here empty! Strange enough, when I start the function F_XXX separately (cut out from the module), it behaves as expected, it means: $Error[0] gives an error back. The code:

> Blockquote

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
Function F1
{
    try
    {
    # do something
    }
    catch
    {
        # 1. cascade Error to Main?
        # throw $Error[0].InnerException
        # or
        # local Error-Logging?
        write-MyErrorLogging -message $Error[0].InnerException
    }
}



Function F2
{
    try
    {
        # do something
    }
    catch
    {
        # 1. cascade Error to Main?
        # throw $Error[0].InnerException
        # or
        # local Error-Logging?
        write-MyErrorLogging -message $Error[0].InnerException
    }
}
Function F_XXXXXX
{
    try
    {
        cls
        write-host "The install data is copied.."
        $share = "\\my_wrong_path\sql_sources\" 
        Copy-Item $share -Destination $installDrive -Force -Recurse
    }
    catch
    {
        $Error[0] #here is nothing!
        $null -eq $Error[0] # here true
        $_.Exception # only here the error-message: wrong path!
    }
}
```

> Blockquote

```
# here Main
try
{
    F1
    F2
    F_XXXXXX
}
catch
{
    write-MyErrorLogging -message $Error[0].InnerException
}
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Inside a `catch` block**, it's best to *avoid* `$Error[0]`, given that **the error at hand is reliably reflected in the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_)**.

  - If you do need access to *previous* errors via the [automatic `$Error` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#error), **use `$global:Error` inside modules** - see the bottom section for details.
- Unless you need to perform *additional* actions when an error occurs, you can let a script-terminating (fatal) error (which your `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` statement turns *all* errors in your code into) bubble up the call stack until it is either caught by a [`try` / `catch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) or, in the absence of one, terminates the entire call stack (i.e., the scripts and its callers).

  - If you do need to perform additional actions, use `try` / `catch`, and place the actions inside the `catch` block (as well as potential cleanup actions in a `finally` block), followed by *re-throwing* the error simply by calling `throw` *without an argument*.

Thus, you can make do with a *single* `try` / `catch` statement in the top-level scope of your script:

```
# Turn all errors in this and descendant scopes into
# script-terminating (fatal) ones.
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# ... other function definitions, without try / catch

# Top-level code that calls the other functions and catches
# any errors.
try
{
    F1
    F2
    F_XXXXXX
}
catch
{
    write-MyErrorLogging -message $_.InnerException
}
```

---

**The [automatic `$Error` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#error) in modules:**

Strangely, up to at least PowerShell 7.2.3 (current as of this writing):

- Errors occurring in modules - just like ones occurring outside modules - *are* recorded in the `$Error` variable that exists in the *global* scope.
- However, **a seemingly *unused, module-local copy* of `$Error` exists, which *shadows* the global variable**, both in Windows PowerShell and in [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) up to at least v7.3.7 (current as of this writing). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11457624/45375) for the history behind this problem, and [GitHub issue #20458](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20458) for a discussion about fixing it.

The workaround is to use **use `$global:Error` from inside modules**.

The behavior suggests a bug, given that the module-local copy is seemingly never touched and serves no apparent purpose.

Comment: thanks, 1. I'll probably use the error handling in the top-level scope.
2. there is definitely something wrong in the Function F_XXXX, the path is wrong and I don't get anything (!) catching the $Error[0] - variable (see the code), only $_ variable has the error message. Why is here $Error[0] losing the error?

Comment: I found an old one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521935/error-variable-is-null-but-contains-error-in-catch
$error is an automatic variable handled by Powershell: 3rd § of the LONG DESCRIPTION in about_Try_Catch_Finally.
It is considered as the context of the Catch block, thus being available as $_. Since Catch block is a different block than Try, 
the $error automatic variable is reset and valued $null.
The Problem with the reproducible example is: the strange behaviour happens only in the whole module, when I cut the Function F_XXX out and run it separately everything is fine..

Comment: ..it's a quite old problem described in the link above, now I'm using the last desktop version of PowerShell (5.1.xxx)..

Comment: @Purclot, the problem exists to this day (PowerShell 7.2.3, as of this writing). Please see my update, which also shows a workaround (`$global:Error`). The explanation in the answer you quote isn't correct.

Comment: thanks, a great job, really appreciate it! How the heck did you find it out??

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @Purclot; my pleasure. As for how I diagnosed the problem: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72164560/45375) I've just added to the post you linked to.

Comment: hi mklement0, is it possible you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73403089/powershell-runtime-execption-in-remote-call ..? I'd appreciate it very much..